# Electron builder - how to include Bootstrap icons and access files into build correctly

Tags: vue.js, ms-access, electron, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons

I've created a simple Electron and Vue app that will have bootstrap 5.3.0 and bootstrap icons as dependency. During the serve mode of vue Electron cli plugin the serve mode will load all the needed assets without problems, but after I build the app, I've noticed that some MS Access `.mdb` files and Bootstrap icons I've used into the app, will be not loaded.

In console for the icons in particular I will get a not found error, and it's like the needed svg files for the icons and the Access files are not bundled. I'm using vue 3 that will be using vite as a module bundler, I've tried to follow the suggested configuration that is explained [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents) but without result.

How can I correctly load Bootstrap icons and extra files like the Access files I need correctly? Is it possible to have a portable app that will use these files if included into the same folder where the exe will be generated?